# authenticating user using pbkdf2 hash algorithm by https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm

Tags: php, hash, authentication, web, salt

i am currently using md5 to authenticate users after they put their login email and password :

```
if($_POST['submit']=='Login')
{
    // Checking whether the Login form has been submitted

// Will hold our errors
$err = array();


if(!$_POST['email'] || !$_POST['main_password'])
    $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';

if(!count($err))
{
    // Make this an integer.
    $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];

    try {

        $sql = "SELECT id,email FROM ld_customers WHERE email = :cust_email AND password = :cust_password";
        $stmt = $iws_db->prepare($sql);


        $stmt->bindParam(':cust_email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
        $stmt->bindParam(':cust_password', md5($_POST['main_password']) , PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);

        $stmt->execute();   
        $row = $stmt->fetch();

    if($row['email'])
    {

        // If everything is OK login and write the users data to the session.
        $_SESSION['email']=$row['email'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

        // Store some data in the session

        setcookie('iwsRemember',$_POST['rememberMe']);
    }

    else $err[]='Wrong email and/or password!';

    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $iws_db = null;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

if($err)
$_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
// Save the error messages in the session

header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
```

but i want to now authenticate using **PBKDF2** by https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm.Here is the snippet of code by them:

```
    <?php

define("PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM", "sha256");
define("PBKDF2_ITERATIONS", 10000);
define("PBKDF2_HASH_BYTES", 24);
define("PBKDF2_SALT_BYTES", 24);

define("HASH_SECTIONS", 4);
define("HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX", 0);
define("HASH_ITERATION_INDEX", 1);
define("HASH_SALT_INDEX", 2);
define("HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX", 3);

function create_hash($password)
{
    // format: algorithm:iterations:salt:hash
    $salt = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(PBKDF2_SALT_BYTES, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));     
    return PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM . ":" . PBKDF2_ITERATIONS . ":" .  $salt . ":" . 
        base64_encode(pbkdf2(
            PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM,
            $password,
            $salt,
            PBKDF2_ITERATIONS,
            PBKDF2_HASH_BYTES,
            true
        ));
}

function validate_password($password, $good_hash)
{
    $params = explode(":", $good_hash);
    if(count($params) < HASH_SECTIONS)
       return false; 
    $pbkdf2 = base64_decode($params[HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX]);
    return slow_equals(
        $pbkdf2,
        pbkdf2(
            $params[HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX],
            $password,
            $params[HASH_SALT_INDEX],
            (int)$params[HASH_ITERATION_INDEX],
            strlen($pbkdf2),
            true
        )
    );
}




function slow_equals($a, $b)
{
    $diff = strlen($a) ^ strlen($b);
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($a) && $i < strlen($b); $i++)
    {
        $diff |= ord($a[$i]) ^ ord($b[$i]);
    }
    return $diff === 0; 
}

function pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output = false)
{
    $algorithm = strtolower($algorithm);
    if(!in_array($algorithm, hash_algos(), true))
        die('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid hash algorithm.');
    if($count <= 0 || $key_length <= 0)
        die('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid parameters.');

    $hash_length = strlen(hash($algorithm, "", true));
    $block_count = ceil($key_length / $hash_length);

    $output = "";
    for($i = 1; $i <= $block_count; $i++) {
        // $i encoded as 4 bytes, big endian.
        $last = $salt . pack("N", $i);
        // first iteration
        $last = $xorsum = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true);
        // perform the other $count - 1 iterations
        for ($j = 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
            $xorsum ^= ($last = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true));
        }
        $output .= $xorsum;
    }

    if($raw_output)
        return substr($output, 0, $key_length);
    else
        return bin2hex(substr($output, 0, $key_length));
}
?>
```

i tried doing implementing this in this way:

```
  if($_POST['submit']=='Login')
    {
        // Checking whether the Login form has been submitted

    // Will hold our errors
    $err = array();


    if(!$_POST['email'] || !$_POST['main_password'])
        $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';

    if(!count($err))
    {
        // Make this an integer.
        $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];

        try {

            $sql = "SELECT id,email FROM ld_customers WHERE email = :cust_email";
        $stmt = $iws_db->prepare($sql);

        /*** bind the paramaters ***/
        $stmt->bindParam(':cust_email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);




        $stmt->execute();

        $row = $stmt->fetch();

                    if(!validate_password($_POST['main_password'], $row['password']))
                    {
                     exit("Password error!");
                    }
                     else
                    {
                     if($row['email'])
             {
              // If everything is OK login and write the users data to the session.
        $_SESSION['email']=$row['email'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

        // Store some data in the session

        setcookie('iwsRemember',$_POST['rememberMe']);    

        }
                    else
                    {
                    $err[]='Wrong email and/or password!';
                    }
                   }


    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $iws_db = null;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

if($err)
$_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
// Save the error messages in the session

header("Location: index.php");
exit;
```

i am not successful implementing it, every time it exit saying **password error!!** i think the problem is fetching the stored encrypted password and comparing it with password input by user.

Comment: i am not able to implement it.every time the error is coming wrong email and password!!

Comment: Have you somehow converted all your password hashes in your database to PBKDF2?

Comment: yes i converted them to hash by using create_hash function as mention in above file.

Comment: The problem is that you *can't* convert the pre-existing MD5 hashes to PBKDF2, which is something you'd have to do to change the hash method.

Comment: i deleted all the previous stored md5 hashed passwords and tested with newly created hashed paswwords. the password are stored properly in hashed format in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be something like:

```
    $sql = "SELECT id,email FROM ld_customers WHERE email = :cust_email";
    $stmt = $iws_db->prepare($sql);


    $stmt->bindParam(':cust_email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);

    $stmt->execute();   
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
if($row['email'])
{
  if(!validate_password($_POST['main_password'], $row['password']))
  {
     exit("Password error!");
  }
  else
  {
    echo'Logged in!';
  }
}
else
   echo"email doesn't exist";
```

You are creating an MD5 hash instead of using the functions of your library.